# Why install.packages and download.file aren't working while RCurl::getURL is?

Tags: r

I have trouble with installing packages from internet:

```
> install.packages("qualV")
Warning in install.packages :
  InternetOpenUrl failed: 'The server name or address could not be resolved'
Warning in install.packages :
  InternetOpenUrl failed: 'The server name or address could not be resolved'
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository https://mirror.ibcp.fr/pub/CRAN/src/contrib
Warning in install.packages :
  InternetOpenUrl failed: 'The server name or address could not be resolved'
Warning in install.packages :
  InternetOpenUrl failed: 'The server name or address could not be resolved'
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin/src/contrib
Warning in install.packages :
  InternetOpenUrl failed: 'The server name or address could not be resolved'
Warning in install.packages :
  InternetOpenUrl failed: 'The server name or address could not be resolved'
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository https://mirror.ibcp.fr/pub/CRAN/src/contrib
Warning in install.packages :
  InternetOpenUrl failed: 'The server name or address could not be resolved'
Warning in install.packages :
  InternetOpenUrl failed: 'The server name or address could not be resolved'
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin/src/contrib
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘qualV’ is not available (for R version 3.2.2)
Warning in install.packages :
  InternetOpenUrl failed: 'The server name or address could not be resolved'
Warning in install.packages :
  InternetOpenUrl failed: 'The server name or address could not be resolved'
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository https://mirror.ibcp.fr/pub/CRAN/bin/windows/contrib/3.2
Warning in install.packages :
  InternetOpenUrl failed: 'The server name or address could not be resolved'
Warning in install.packages :
  InternetOpenUrl failed: 'The server name or address could not be resolved'
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin/bin/windows/contrib/3.2
```

I've checked the repositories, proxy and set debug info:

```
> options(internet.info = 0)
> options()$repos
                                CRAN                            CRANextra 
  "https://mirror.ibcp.fr/pub/CRAN/" "http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin" 
attr(,"RStudio")
[1] TRUE
>
> Sys.getenv("http_proxy")
[1] ""
> Sys.getenv("https_proxy")
[1] ""
```

I've unchecked: `R-studio->Tools->Global Options->Use Internet Explorer library/proxy for HTTP` (I've also tried pure R without R-studio with same results)

Seems the problem is with internet access:

```
> url.link <- "https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/download.file.html"
> content  <- download.file(url.link, destfile = "download.file.html")
trying URL 'https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/download.file.html'
Error in download.file(url.link, destfile = "download.file.html") : 
  cannot open URL 'https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/download.file.html'
In addition: Warning message:
In download.file(url.link, destfile = "download.file.html") :
  InternetOpenUrl failed: 'The server name or address could not be resolved'
```

Here comes interesting part, seems that the problem is not with internet access:

```
> library(RCurl)
> content <- getURL(url.link)
> nchar(content)
[1] 13537
```

Why `install.packages` and `download.file` aren't working while `getURL` is working?

PS: OS is Windows 7 running on corporate notebook so there are AV/FW installed that I cannot disable (I'm not admininstrator).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a guess.

I think you have a new version of RStudio but an old version of R. In my experience you can install the package if you just use R, i.e. not through RStudio. I would recommend updating both R and RStudio to the latest versions.

---

I think the issue arises because RStudio enforces https, which is only introduced in a later version of R.

Comment: I've done this but the result was the same as previous. Then I've disabled proxy in Internet Explorer and enabled `R-studio->Tools->Global Options->Use Internet Explorer library/proxy for HTTP`. Now it is working. Thanks.